# C++ C2040: 'Block***' differs in levels of indirection (& memory assistance)

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, heap-memory, allocation

I've looked many places without finding enough information to help me solve my issue. Basically, I want a three dimensional array of 16*16*256 instances of a class. This caused a stack overflow, so I attempted a vector but that also crashed. Finally, I am attempting to allocate heap memory via triple, double, and single pointers.

```
/* Values chunkX, chunkY, chunkZ used below are static constant integers*/
Block*** blocks;
blocks = new Block**[chunkX];
for (int i = 0; i < chunkX; i++) {//Initialize all arrays
    blocks[i] = new Block*[chunkZ];
    for (int u = 0; u < chunkZ; u++) {
        blocks[i][u] = new Block[chunkY];
    }
}
```

This made sense to me but probably is incorrect. The **C2040** error is at the line where *blocks* is first defined.

Later in the code, I attempt:

```
Block& block = blocks[x][z][y];
```

But it tells me **C2530** *'block': references must be initialized* ... even though I initialized them above..? And then it just stops compiling because of these two errors. I'm quite confused and couldn't find any triple pointer tutorials using *new*. I don't think the amount of memory I want is unreasonable, because the Block class isn't huge.

**EDIT (SOLVED):**
Apparently this was not a code problem but just the compiler bugging out. It compiles now without changes made. Thanks for the comments and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: A vector doesn't randomly crash if you use it properly (e.g., don't access it out of bounds with `operator[]`).

Comment: [std::vector works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65e61b71f847df96).  You could have simply used `at()` to access your elements using `vector`, to ensure that you are not going out-of-bounds.

Comment: *I'm quite confused and couldn't find any triple pointer tutorials using new* -- That is because whoever would write such a tutorial would be derided (and rightfully so) as a *3 star programmer*.

Comment: You have to show at least an entire function, those errors make no sense at all unless you are reusing variable names.

Comment: Does not repro: http://ideone.com/tNMbb6